# Питон отправить объект по get запросу с urlencode

Tags: python, json, urlencode

Здравствуйте,надо результат распознанной команды от гугл ассистента отправить с помощью get запроса на сервер обработчик.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    # Copyright (C) 2017 Google Inc.
    #
    # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    # You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.


    from __future__ import print_function

    import argparse
    import os.path
    import json
    import urllib

    import google.oauth2.credentials

    from google.assistant.library import Assistant
    from google.assistant.library.event import EventType
    from google.assistant.library.file_helpers import existing_file


    def process_event(event):
        """Pretty prints events.

        Prints all events that occur with two spaces between each new
        conversation and a single space between turns of a conversation.

        Args:
        event(event.Event): The current event to process.
        """
        if event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED:
        print()

        print(event)

        if (event.type == EventType.ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED and
            event.args and not event.args['with_follow_on_turn']):
        print()

        if event.type == EventType.ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
    #        isay = event.args['text']
            cmd = str(event.args['text'])
            isay = {'qry':cmd}
            current_url = 'http://192.168.1.44/command.php?' % urllib.parse.urlencode(isay)

    #        isay = ('qry',event.args['text'])
    #        isay = object.__str__(event.args['text'])
    #        print('I listen: ', isay)
    #        current_url = 'http://192.168.1.44/command.php?qry=' % urllib.parse.urlencode(str(isay))
    #        current_url = 'http://192.168.1.44/command.php?qry=' % urllib.parse.quote(isay)
    #        urllib.urlopen(current_url)
    #        print('Command: ', current_url)

    def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
        parser.add_argument('--credentials', type=existing_file,
                metavar='OAUTH2_CREDENTIALS_FILE',
                default=os.path.join(
                    os.path.expanduser('~/.config'),
                    'google-oauthlib-tool',
                    'credentials.json'
                ),
                help='Path to store and read OAuth2 credentials')
        args = parser.parse_args()
        with open(args.credentials, 'r') as f:
        credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(token=None,
                                    **json.load(f))

        with Assistant(credentials) as assistant:
        for event in assistant.start():
            process_event(event)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

В таком исполнении ругается:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Помогите пожалуйста исправить код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой `requests`. С помощью нее можно быстро делать `get` и `post` запросы, при этом в качестве параметров запроса передаётся объект, который библиотека сама сериализует.
Пример:

```
import requests
data = {"a":"foo", "key2": 1}
r = requests.get("http://example.com", params=data)
print(r.text)
```

В результате получится такой url:

```
http://example.com/?a=foo&key2=1
```

Текст ответа будет выведен на консоль.
Подробнее с документацией можно ознакомиться в [Request Quickstart](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо буду пробовать. Здесь есть кнопка благодарности?